# SQL Server Timeout: Gathering server side information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We use SQL Server 2008 for our database. We use a combination of Classic ASP and .NET to connect to said database. We get random timeouts on queries that are extremely simple and when we run said queries they appear to be quick and have the correct indexes.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to have SQL Server gather/keep data on these timeouts and send it to us. I've read in the past that you can do this for deadlocks.

Comment: Might be worth seeing [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/sql-server-concurrency-performance/4335#4335).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (at least some of) these "random timeouts" might be network related?

You should definitely consider performance monitor.  You can view statistics in real time, collect statistics to generate a baseline, and configure triggers to send alerts.

PS:
Here's a good link to get you started:

[Free Microsoft Tools to Help Setup and Maintain PerfMon for SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1607/free-microsoft-tools-to-help-setup-and-maintain-perfmon-for-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your while to check all activity on the server, not just what you are sending it.

Read about SQL Server Profiler on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server%20profiler&submit=search) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

There may be external factors affecting this as well, and getting your DBA / System Admin involved may be a good idea.

Comment: There really isn't a so much of a DBA to speak of. I know about and use Profiler, but don't know how to use it effectively in this case.